# web用画像の解像度は72ppiと教えられましたが最近は…？

Tags: html, css

web用画像の解像度についてですが、最近も72ppiが定番なのでしょうか？
できるだけ綺麗に見せたいです。
retina用に2倍のサイズで画像を用意することは知っているのですが、
弊社のサイトは画像が多いので(ECサイト系)
重くなりそうでそれはできません。

最近のweb用画像の主流の解像度(ppi)を教えて頂けたら幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

> retina用に2倍のサイズで画像を用意することは知っているのですが、
>   弊社のサイトは画像が多いので(ECサイト系)
>   重くなりそうでそれはできません。

結論はもう出ているのでは？

なお、現在は[CSSメディアクエリ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)を用いることによってデバイスのサイズや解像度に応じてスタイルを切り替えることができます。
複数の解像度で画像を用意しておき、デバイスに応じて選択されることをお勧めします。